# Collect the sum of combined values

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute a query to display a customers balance along with the combined amount of several customer related charges so I can check if the total balance matches the combined balance.

I think I need to use a GROUP BY in my query but it has proved unsuccessful so far. My attempt is as follows:

```
select c.ID, m.Balance, SUM(chg.Balance) as CombinedBalance
from Customer c
INNER JOIN ChargeTemplate chg
on c.ID = chg.CustomerID
WHERE c.Balance <> (SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM ChargeTemplate WHERE chg.CustomerID= c.ID )
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Balance
order by c.ID ASC
```

The above query outputs the total balance and the total combined balance but it also displays the records where the `c.Balance` is equal to the Combined balance.

The below query does the exact same thing as the above query, *even though I have removed the WHERE clause.*

```
select c.ID, c.Balance, SUM(chg.Balance) as CombinedBalance
from Customer c
INNER JOIN ChargeTemplate chg
on c.ID = chg.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Balance
order by c.ID ASC
```

My desired output is the `CUSTOMERTABLE.BALANCE` value with the corresponding combined total of the customers charges - this way, I can compare the actual balance matches the combined amount.  How can I make this a reality?

Note: The chargetable has a CustomerTable.CustomerID FK

[image]

Customer 1:

```
CUSTOMERTABLE.TOTAL_BALANCE = 100.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[1].BALANCE = 20.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[2].BALANCE = 30.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[3].BALANCE = 50.00
```

Customer 2:

```
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[1].BALANCE = 10.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[2].BALANCE = 20.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[3].BALANCE = 30.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[4].BALANCE = 90.00
CHARGETABLE.CHARGE[5].BALANCE = 50.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter on aggregates, use the HAVING clause

```
Select
    c.ID, m.Balance, Sum(chg.Balance) as CombinedBalance
From 
    Customer c
        Inner Join
    ChargeTemplate chg
        On c.ID = chg.CustomerID
Group By 
    c.ID, c.Balance
Having 
    m.Balance != Sum(chg.Balance)
Order By
    c.ID ASC
```

Comment: Excellent.. thanks Laurence.. done the job. Much appreciated.